# How to find all solutions under some constraints using JuMP in Julia

Tags: julia, linear-programming, julia-jump

As mentioned, I want to find all possible variable combinations that satisfy some linear constraints. More specifically, I want to get a random choice in all these combinations.

Normally, an LP problem in JuMP can be described and solved as follows:

```
model = Model(optimizer_with_attributes(() -> Gurobi.Optimizer(GRB_ENV), "OutputFlag"=>0))
@variable(model, x >= 0::Int)
@variable(model, y >= 0::Int)
@objective(model, Max, x-y) # not required
@constraint(model, x+y<=3)
optimize!(model)
```

In my case, I don't need an objective function but I want to get all possible solutions that satisfy the constraints. In this example, I want to acquire the following solutions to get a random choice:

```
all_xy_combs = [(0,3), (1,2), (2,1), (3,0)]
# acquire a random choice from combs
(x,y) = sample(all_xy_combs)
```

Is it possible using JuMP?

Comment: A usual method to get all solutions, is to add constraints which rule out previously found solutions and re-solve. But some solvers have an interface to get more/all solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not generally possible in JuMP. But it is possible for some solvers to return multiple solutions by setting solver-specific parameters.

For example:

```
julia> using JuMP, Gurobi

julia> model = Model(Gurobi.Optimizer);

julia> set_silent(model)

julia> set_attribute(model, "PoolSearchMode", 2)

julia> set_attribute(model, "PoolSolutions", GRB_MAXINT)

julia> @variable(model, x >= 0, Int)
x

julia> @variable(model, y >= 0, Int)
y

julia> @constraint(model, x + y <= 3)
x + y ≤ 3.0

julia> @objective(model, Max, x - y)
x - y

julia> optimize!(model)

julia> solutions = map(1:result_count(model)) do i
           return (
               x = value(x; result = i), 
               y = value(y; result = i),
               obj = objective_value(model; result = i),
           )
       end
10-element Vector{NamedTuple{(:x, :y, :obj), Tuple{Float64, Float64, Float64}}}:
 (x = 3.0, y = -0.0, obj = 3.0)
 (x = 2.0, y = -0.0, obj = 2.0)
 (x = 1.0, y = -0.0, obj = 1.0)
 (x = 2.0, y = 1.0, obj = 1.0)
 (x = -0.0, y = -0.0, obj = -0.0)
 (x = 1.0, y = 1.0, obj = -0.0)
 (x = 1.0, y = 2.0, obj = -1.0)
 (x = -0.0, y = 1.0, obj = -1.0)
 (x = -0.0, y = 2.0, obj = -2.0)
 (x = -0.0, y = 3.0, obj = -3.0)
```

https://www.gurobi.com/documentation/9.5/refman/poolsearchmode.html#parameter:PoolSearchMode
https://www.gurobi.com/documentation/9.5/refman/poolsolutions.html#parameter:PoolSolutions

Comment: Hi @Oscar, I tried your code but change the PoolSearchMode to 1 considering my project. But in this case, I only get one result. 1-element Vector{NamedTuple{(:x, :y, :obj), Tuple{Float64, Float64, Float64}}}:
 (x = 3.0, y = -0.0, obj = 3.0) Do you know why is that?

Comment: Read the Gurobi documentation for PoolSearchMode:

> With a setting of 1, there are no guarantees about the quality of the extra solutions, while with a setting of 2, the solver will find the n best solutions

Comment: I thought solutions with no guarantees means that we will get n random solutions from all possible solutions, but in this case it won’t give any solutions at all.

Comment: I interpreted "the MIP solver will try to find n solutions" as sometimes it won't find extra solutions.